# Reversing Log-transformed target after training : r2 score interpretation

Tags: regression, data-transformation, back-transformation

I have been running a log-transform on my target values because the distribution appears to be highly right skewed as you can see in the picture.[image]

After having called

```
df['target'] = np.log(df['target'])
```

the distribution target looks like this
[image]

that is way better than before for training a model.

At this point I run the ML process and I train my model on log-scaled targets getting the following predictions (still using the log-scaled targets):

[image]

obtained by simply plotting log scaled predictions against log scaled true values, where the red line is the 'ideal' linear relationship between predictions and targets that I'm trying to achieve.

I got an R2 score of 0.40 which is not amazing but is not too bad at the moment.

The problem is, that when I try to get back to the original values by an inverse transform, i.e.

```
preds = np.exp(model.predict(X_test))
y_test = np.exp(y_test)
```

then I get the following:

[image]

and a R2 score of -0.090 obtained by running

```
r2_score(y_test, preds)
```

(hence using the inverse transformed values).

What am I doing wrong?

thank you in advance,

James

Answer (score 2):

You should be calculating r2_score on the test data that is transformed in the same manner as the train data.
In your case, the data that is transformed with log transformation, as the weights that are learned in the training part work with the transformed data.

Therefore, no need to do:
preds = np.exp(model.predict(X_test))
y_test = np.exp(y_test)

Run the s2_score on preds and y_test without the np.exp transformation.

Comment: Thank you that's what I have done in the end... Now the question is, how should I look at these *transformed errors* I mean what is the effect of taking the log, it will *shrink* the errors that I do as well.

Comment: I think this [link](https://florianwilhelm.info/2020/05/honey_i_shrunk_the_target_variable/) sums up the answer to your question . You can't "shrink" the target without a potential problem with "shrinking".